# Sorting and Removing from list Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dict and each dict in list have a timestamp in string format and a key. A particular key can repeat multiple times in list. I want to only keep the dict with key which has latest timestamp and eliminate/remove all other dicts from the list. One way i have implemented the soluion is by using another variable and looping over all keys and comparing with exiting one.

Is there any better way to solve this issue using list comprehension or itertools or any other way

Here is sample Input Data

```
data = [
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:21.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:22.762278'},
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:23.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:19.762278'},
    {'key': 'key3', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:25.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:11.762278'},
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:45.762278'},
    {'key': 'key4', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:39.762278'}
]
```

Here is what is expected as output

```
data = [
    {'key': 'key3', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:25.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:22.762278'},
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:45.762278'},
    {'key': 'key4', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:39.762278'}
]
```

My Implementation in python is as follow

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
def sort_and_eliminate(data):
    processed_data = {}
    for cur_item in data:
        key = cur_item.get('key')
        if key not in processed_data:
            processed_data[key] = cur_item
        else:
            ex_item = processed_data.get(key)
            ex_ts = parse(ex_item.get("timestamp"))
            cur_ts = parse(cur_item.get("timestamp"))
            if cur_ts > ex_ts:
                processed_data[key] = cur_item
    return processed_data.values()
```

Is there any better way to solve this issue using list comprehension or itertools or any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
from dateutil.parser import parse

expected = [
    {'key': 'key3', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:25.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:22.762278'},
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:45.762278'},
    {'key': 'key4', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:39.762278'}
]

data = [
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:21.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:22.762278'},
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:23.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:19.762278'},
    {'key': 'key3', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:25.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:11.762278'},
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:45.762278'},
    {'key': 'key4', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:39.762278'}
]


# alt way without dateutil
def dtconv(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")

ds = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x['key'], parse(x['timestamp'])), reverse=True)

result = []
for grouper, group in groupby(ds, key=itemgetter('key')):
    result.append(next(group))

print("result:")
for r in result:
    print(r)

print("expected")
for e in expected:
    print(e)

# demonstrate it's equal to expected value
print(sorted(result, key=itemgetter('key')) == sorted(expected, key=itemgetter('key')))
```

Try sorting the list by key and datestamp. Then you can do a `groupby` and take the first element and that will be what you want to keep.

Comment: It will take more time compared to implementation provided in question

Comment: @akashdeep even if that is true. It much clearer and easier to reason about. The OP asks for a better solution, that doesn't necessarily mean it has to be faster. Hardly a reason to down vote but it's your prerogative.

Comment: Also consider the final two sorts are for demonstration purposes. I hope you didn't include those in your timings?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.

Sort the dictionary based on key and timestamp.

```
x=sorted(data, key=lambda k: (k['key'],k['timestamp']), reverse=True)
print(x)

[{'key': 'key4', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:39.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key3', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:25.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:22.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:19.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:11.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:45.762278'},  
 {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:23.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:21.762278'}]
```

Create a New list and insert only the first occurrence of the key

```
new_list=[]
temp=None
for values in x:
  if values['key']!=temp:
    new_list.append(values)
    temp=values['key']
print(new_list)

[{'key': 'key4', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:39.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key3', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:25.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:22.762278'}, 
 {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:45.762278'}]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

data = [
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:21.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:22.762278'},
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:23.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:19.762278'},
    {'key': 'key3', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:25.762278'},
    {'key': 'key2', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:11.762278'},
    {'key': 'key1', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:45.762278'},
    {'key': 'key4', 'timestamp': '2017-08-03T10:24:39.762278'}]


all_keys = [k['key'] for k in data]

all_keys_unique = set(all_keys)

new_dict = {}

for k in all_keys_unique:

    #find all values for that key and parse them
    values_of_key = [j['timestamp'] for j in data if k == j['key']]

    parsed_values = [parse(k2) for k2 in values_of_key]

    #use max to find latest time step, works on datetimes
    #and add to dictionary
    new_dict[k] = max(parsed_values)

print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data by reverse order of your timestamp string, then the first appearance of each unique key will be the one you want to keep.

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x["timestamp"], reverse=True) 
used_keys, cleaned_data = [ ], [ ]
for item in data:
    if not item['key'] in used_keys:
        # if a key that we encounter in the list isn't used yet,
        # add its corresponding item to cleaned_data and add it to
        # used_keys so we know not to use it again.
        cleaned_data.append(item)
        used_keys.append(item['key'])
```

Comment: Just noticed someone posted basically exactly this. Oh well.

Comment: Fixed. The question doesn't mention anything about preserving the original order of the remaining keys so I assume sorting by timestamp is fine.

Comment: Yes sorting by timestamp is fine. order is not required

Comment: Please explain why and how your code solves the problem instead of posting a code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

just creating another dict with keys value  as key and compare the timestamp and insert latest timestamp as value.